# UV is Mapping to Multiple Meshes

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Can anybody explain why when I am in Object View, with Viewport Shading color set to "Textured", my UV map is correct for all the objects in my scene..

BUT when I switch over to LookDev Mode it maps the texture for one object over several objects? Attatched are pictures of Object Mode and LookDev as well as the blend file.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm at a loss here.

[image: Object and LookDev]

[Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t03cp40irqk7n3r/IT_1_Bell.blend?dl=0)

Comment: I found the issue with the material assignment, but the blend file always needs the images packed into it so that they don't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Your bell, archway and other parts are all sharing the same material node tree which means the objects will all share the same pixels in the image texture. Separate them by pressing the '12' next to the material name'Stone arch' to create individual user materials that can be changed, or assign them new material altogether.